# The error when trying to fetch the list of topics from my database SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a practice API, and these are my classes. The entities and relationships are saved correctly if I use Postman. The API also works with JWT, and that also works correctly as it generates the access token normally.

The problem I have is that when trying to fetch all the topics from the database with the GET method, I encounter 4 errors in the console.

1- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

2- java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

3- org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

4- jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.

I want to emphasize that the endpoint to fetch the topics is public, and it has no restrictions.

Here is my 'user' entity.

```
@Table(name="usuario", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username","email"})}) @Entity public class Usuario implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String curso;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role rol;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "usu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Topico> lista_topicos;


@OneToMany (mappedBy = "usu_respuesta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Respuesta> lista_respuestas;
}
```

The 'Topico' entity.

```
@Entity
 public class Topico {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_topico;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String titulo;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String mensaje;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecha_creacion;
@Convert(converter = TrueFalseConverter.class)
private boolean estado;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "usu_id")
private Usuario usu;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Respuesta> lista_respuesta;
}
```

The 'respuesta' entity.

```
@Entity
public class Respuesta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_respuesta;
private String texto_respuesta;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "topico_id")
private Topico topic;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Usuario usu_respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your error doesnt have anything to do with your entities so no need to post them. its probably confusing.

Now on the security problem, if you do POST requests and everything works fine, but the GET request is failing id say check the solution mentioned here. and even if this doesnt work, focus on your actual problem, which is security error when returning a body

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12758

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed the steps in the post and was able to solve two of the four problems. I still have the following:

1- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

2- java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Comment: ok thats a different one. this is also solved. found couple of links online. the most accurate looks to be this one: https://www.appsloveworld.com/hibernate/100/22/hibernate-and-jackson-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-call-senderror-a

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to solve it using that solution. The problem I have now is that it brings the topic but without the user ID (usu_id).
Example:
 {
        "id_topico": 1,
        "titulo": "Feliz cumpleaños",
        "mensaje": "Hoy celebramos el cumpleaños de María",
        "fecha_creacion": "2023-09-08",
        "estado": false,
        "lista_respuesta": [
            {
                "id_respuesta": 4,
                "texto_respuesta": "feliz cumpleaños"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: This is the HQL statement I am using:

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT t FROM Topico t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.usu u LEFT JOIN FETCH t.lista_respuesta r")
    List<Topico> obtenerTopicosConUsuarioYRespuestas();

Comment: if the initial topic is resolved please mark the response as correct and the thread as resolved. so that we keep this service clean. for next issues you can raise new threads so that you help others who might face the same issue. dont burry it in comments. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am not quiet shure about the solution but you can allow cross origin in you controll class
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
Here is more code example [my github](https://github.com/deidine/inventory_managment_springboot_angular/blob/main/backend/src/main/java/net/javaguides/springboot/controller/EntiteController.java)